# Record with latest date, where date comes from a joined table

Tags: sql

I have tried every answer that I have found to finding the last record, and I have failed in getting a successful result. I currently have a query that lists active trailers. I am needing it to only show a single row for each trailer entry, where that row is based on a date in a joined table.

I have tables
trailer, company, equipment_group, movement, stop

In order to connect trailer to stop (which is where the date is), i have to join it to equipment group, which joins to movement, which then joins to stop.

I have tried using MAX and GROUP BY, and PARTITION BY, both of which error out.

I have tried many solutions here, as well as these
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ordering-within-a-sql-group-by-clause
https://www.geeksengine.com/article/get-single-record-from-duplicates.html

It seems that all of these solutions have the date in the same table as the thing that they want to group by, which I do not.

```
SELECT
 trailer.*
 company.name, 
 equipment_group.currentmovement_id, 
 equipment_group.company_id, 
 movement.dest_stop_id, stop.location_id, 
 stop.*
FROM trailer 
LEFT OUTER JOIN company ON (company.id = trailer.company_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN equipment_group ON (equipment_group.id = 
trailer.currenteqpgrpid) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN movement ON (movement.id = 
equipment_group.currentmovement_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN stop ON (stop.id = movement.dest_stop_id)
WHERE trailer.is_active = 'A'
```

Using MAX and GROUP BY gives error "invalid in the select list... not contained in...aggregate function"

Comment: What's the database? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, Sybase, etc.

Comment: You need to create a row_number partitioned by trailer (or whatever makes sense), order by date (perhaps descending) and then select only the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Welllllll, I never did end up figuring that out, but if I joined movements on to equipment group by two conditions, all is well. Each extra record was created by each company id.... company id is in EVERY table.